# How to make the dropdown in the top menu to appear without delay/animation?

Tags: javascript, css, delay, drop-down-menu

I have a menu with a dropdown [here](http://bit.ly/Hp9AXq). How do I make the dropdown to appear instantly, like on [this](http://bit.ly/Ie7yZ4) site?

Edit:  I figured out what causing the delay : dropdown wouldn't show up while the mouse is moving, it only shows when mouse is stopped.So if the mouse never stops on the menu item - dropdown would newer even showup...

Edit2: It appears, the problem is only presented in Chrome, FF and IE work as intended..

Comment: Can you be more clear? It looks instant to me.

Comment: i think you need to properly set the dimensions on the `a` element. this will allow the js to activate the menu at the appropriate time ...

Comment: @Ross when compared to menu in second example, you can see there is a about half second delay on mouseover

Comment: @Xander could you please be more specific? are you talking about `a` elements for entire menu or just the `a` in the dropdown?

Comment: just the `a` in the "dropdown" ... as the `hover` event on that element is what triggers the submenu to display ...

Comment: @Ross there isn't. just a ***perceived*** delay if a user hovers over a part of the menu where they think it should display and doesn't due to styling issues on the `a` element ...

Comment: I figured out what causing the delay : dropdown wouldn't show up while the mouse is moving, it only shows when mouse is stopped.So if the mouse never stops on the menu item - dropdown would newer even showup...

Comment: It appears, the problem is only presented in Chrome, FF and IE work as intended..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the browser isn't loading your background image because it is initially hidden.  The delay is caused by that image being requested from the server.  I would pre-load it somehow-- maybe add a dummy pixel-wide div at the bottom of your page with that image as the background-image.

Comment: ok I changed the bg to color rather then a picture, however I still have issues .. I figured out what causing the delay : dropdown wouldn't show up while the mouse is moving, it only shows when mouse is stopped.So if the mouse never stops on the menu item - dropdown would newer even showup...

Comment: It appears, the problem is only presented in Chrome, FF and IE work as intended..

Comment: @Acidon, it seems I can't reproduce.  It looks instantaneous to me in Chrome.